# Loop inside polygon shapefile to clip another shapefile using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I'm a beginner in PyQGIS and need help to figure out how to automate a process in QGIS.

I want to write a script that enables me to loop inside a polygon shapefile (shown in brown) and use extent of each polygon to clip another shapefile (shown in yellowish).

Below is what I figured out so far:

```
    loc_brown= 'D:/Python_Calcs/SHP_PR/brown.shp'
    loc_yellow = 'D:/Python_Calcs/SHP_PR/yellow.shp'

    layer_brown = QgsVectorLayer(loc_brown,'','ogr') 
    layer_yellow = QgsVectorLayer(loc_yellow,'','ogr') 

            for feat in layer_brown.getFeatures():
                    attrs = feat.attributes()
                    print(attrs[0])
                    clip = processing.run("native:clip",'INPUT':layer_yellow,'OVERLAY':????,'OUTPUT':"D:/Python_Calcs/tmp/"+"clip_"+str(attrs[0])+".shp"})
```

[image: Vector_To_Use_For_Clip_Extent]
[image: Vector_To_Clip]

Comment: Would be easier to Intersect then Split Vector Layer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be something like this one, it selects every feature before running the algorithm:

```
loc_brown= 'D:/Python_Calcs/SHP_PR/brown.shp'
loc_yellow = 'D:/Python_Calcs/SHP_PR/yellow.shp'

layer_brown = QgsVectorLayer(loc_brown,'','ogr') 
layer_yellow = QgsVectorLayer(loc_yellow,'','ogr') 

for feat in layer_brown.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    print(attrs[0])
    alg_params = {'INPUT': layer_yellow,
            'OVERLAY' : layer_brown,
            'OUTPUT': 'D:/Python_Calcs/tmp/'+'clip_'+str(attrs[0])+'.shp'}    
    layer_brown.selectByIds([feat.id()]) 
    result = processing.run("native:clip", alg_params)
```